# Getting "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'" on django rest "PUT" method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the record with PUT method, Getting AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'.
My models.py:

```
class TableInfo(models.Model):

    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    columns = JSONField(null=False)
```

serializer.py:

```
class TableInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TableInfo
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py :

```
@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def table_info(request):
    try:
        queryset = TableInfo.objects.all()
        print("1")
    except TableInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        print("2")
        serializer_class = TableInfoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        print(request.data)
        serializer = TableInfoSerializer(queryset, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("4")
            return HttpResponse(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

code is breaking at `if serializer.is_valid():`
On "GET" I am getting the result. Please help me with "PUT" method.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @api_view(['GET','PATCH']) if you want PUT then add PUT here.

Comment: update it to `@api_view(['GET','PATCH','PUT'])` . It will work fine.

Comment: @tayyab_fareed Sorry actually In my original code it was "PUT" only, then also facing the same issue.

Comment: I think you need to pass the instance to the serializer rather than the queryset. Firstly get the the object you want to update and than pass it to the serialzer

Comment: or if you want to update the whole queryset that pass `many=True` to the serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens with PUT because the serializer tries to access the Meta class on the model instance it is updating, but fails because you are not passing a model instance - you're passing a queryset as indicated in the comments.

So you need to pass an instance, and to specify which instance you would normally pass the instance id via the URL. For that you would be best to separate out your views, and create a `table_detail` view for retrieving and updating a specific instance.

```py
@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def table_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        table_info = TableInfo.objects.get(pk=pk)  # Lookup a specific object
    except TableInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer_class = TableInfoSerializer(table_info)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TableInfoSerializer(table_info, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Your `table_info` view can then just handle the list operation.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def table_info(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = TableInfo.objects.all()
        serializer_class = TableInfoSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```